# Is $\operatorname{Hom}(G/Z(G),Z(G))$ an abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Is it true that $\operatorname{Hom}(G/Z(G),Z(G))$ is abelian, where $\operatorname{Hom}(G/Z(G),Z(G))$ is the group of all homomorphisms of $G/Z(G)$ to $Z(G)$? Is it possible to have a explicit explanation of this group?

Comment: Homs into an abelian group always forms an abelian group.

Comment: @Yuan.Thanks. and about the second question do you have any idea

Comment: @maryam What do you mean by "explicit explanation"?

Comment: @ Crostul. For example is the group direct product of some copies of $Z(G)$ or something like that?

Comment: It is not true in general that it is a direct product of copies of $Z(G)$. Note that the exponenet of ${\rm Hom}$ group cannot be greater than that of $G/Z(G)$ or of $Z(G)$.